# how to Reverse Relation Serialize N times based on data in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to construct a binary tree like structure(using reverse relation)

an employee with report_to field null is top of the tree(A grade), using reverse serializer I can get their controlled employee list(B grade). but if the B grade employee is controlling some employees then I have to reverse relate that employee list(C grade). some B grade employee may or may not have employee reporting to them. then C grade employee may or may not have employee reporting to them and so on the tree grows till the last employee.

I have an employee table and job_info table

```
        class employee(models.Model):    
            first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
            last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

        class job_info(models.Model):
            employeeid = models.OneToOneField(employee, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
            report_to = models.ForeignKey(employee, on_delete = models.SET_NULL,related_name = "supervisor", null = True)
```

if I need to find a limited amount of reverse serializer, I can write the required amount of reverse relation serializer. but in my case, the tree maybe (0 grade) to (N grade). so how do I write a serializer that can handle N number of reverse serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick way to think of this would be **SerializerMethodField**.
Something like:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class JobInfo(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee, related_name='get_job_info')
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='get_sub_employees_info')

class JobTreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobInfo
        fields = ('employee', 'sub_employees')

    sub_employees = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_sub_employees(self, job_info):
        return __class__(job_info.employee.get_sub_employees_info.all(), many=True).data
```

Note __class__ refers  JobTreeSerializer, it would be like nesting the same serializer in itself.

Comment: the code is working as required, i have few doubts in your code. there is nothing call job_info yet you called here, def get_sub_employees(self, job_info): and here job_info.employee.get_sub_employees_info.all(). can you please explain?

Comment: i didn't understand your doubt. You want to know how job_info variable gets its value? or does this documentation answer your doubts: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield ?